# What are the intrinsic parameters for Camera Module v2, or where can I find them?

Tags: camera

I am considering to replace a device I have with a Pi + Camera Module v2.

It is important for me to know the parameters from the Camera Module, specially the [Angle of View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view), so that I can avoid buying stuff only to find out the Angle of View is unsuitable.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an answer is found [here](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Camera_Module#Technical_Parameters_.28v.2_board.29).

A subset of the info:

> - Lens: f=3.04 mm, f/2.0
> - Angle of View: 62.2 x 48.8 degrees
> - Full-frame SLR lens equivalent: 29 mm
> - Board size: 25 x 23.86 x 9mm
> - Mounting Holes: 4x D=2.20 mm on 12.5 x 21.0 mm centers